# Pycharm. Mercurial history error.

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial, ide, pycharm

I'm getting following error in [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) on `mac os x` when trying to view history for file:

```
[*** failed to import extension hg4ideapromptextension from /private/var/folders/9y/s55zzx7j04d9tb8_2y6hb0vc0000gp/T/prompthooks2221127787198231381.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/9y/s55zzx7j04d9tb8_2y6hb0vc0000gp/T/prompthooks2221127787198231381.py']
```

Where to dig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue with IntelliJ Idea. Seems like restarting it solves it.

The bug is tracked here:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102481

Comment: my bad, it's working now. looks like i was way behind on pycharm updates though, the issue is supposedly fixed in later builds.